# SQL get the most recent duplicate entry with timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
ID          DESCRIPTION                 TIMESTAMP
1            RECEIVER                    00:10:00
1            SENDER                      00:08:00
1            EXECUTOR                    00:05:00
1            SENDER                      00:03:00
```

How do I get the **most recent** 'SENDER' description and find the time difference with another description using my timestamps?

I want to find the time difference between SENDER and EXECUTOR, but I am getting weird results as its picking up BOTH SENDER entries.

Thanks
Adam

Comment: What's the expected result? (With the above table data.)

Comment: Are there any rows with other ID's than 1?

Comment: @jarlh my table has millions of IDs but I put that table together like me selecting ID=1, should have mentioned that sorry.

Comment: Add some more rows of sample data, with at least one other id. What's the expected result for an ID with no SENDER row? With 3 SENDER rows etc.?

Comment: What's the datatype of the column timestamp? or is it just an output of another query? When you say "*time difference with another description*", does it mean with that of any other sender or last recent sender or totally another description? Edit your question and add complete details don't put information in comments.

Comment: @jarlh Im trying to find the difference between the SENDER and EXECUTOR entry for example... but I dont want my query to latch onto the older SENDER duplicate entry.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Data type is time I think

Comment: There's no "time" datatype is Oracle? You don't know which datatype it is? How do you expect us to answer it without giving required information? Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask throughly before you ask a question to know how to ask one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @KaushikNayak thanks for helping me with the query that I specified :)

Comment: @KaushikNayak how about I remove the 2nd part and just ask you, how do I get the most recent SENDER entry from the table ?

Comment: Please give relevant feedback to the responders of your question and say whether it worked for you and accept an answer if you think it works. It will also help others that way.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I have provided relevant feedback to you as all of your comments really helped me achieve my goal :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    t1.timestamp - t2.timestamp
from
    (SELECT 
        timestamp 
    FROM 
        table 
    WHERE 
        description='SENDER' 
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) t1,
    table t2
WHERE
    t2.description = 'your_description'
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use such a mechanish by using `lag` and `row_number` functions :

```
select id, timestamp_diff
  from
(
  with t(ID,DESCRIPTION,TIMESTAMP) as
  (
   select 1,'RECEIVER',to_timestamp('00:10:00','HH24:MI:SS') from dual union all
   select 1,'SENDER',to_timestamp('00:08:00','HH24:MI:SS') from dual union all
   select 1,'EXECUTOR',to_timestamp('00:05:00','HH24:MI:SS') from dual union all
   select 1,'SENDER',to_timestamp('00:03:00','HH24:MI:SS') from dual 
  )
   select t.id, 
          t.timestamp - lag(t.timestamp) over (order by t.timestamp desc) as timestamp_diff,
          row_number() over (order by t.timestamp) as rn 
     from t   
    where t.description = 'SENDER'
)
where rn = 1;

 ID    TIMESTAMP_DIFF
 -- --------------------
 1  -000000000 00:05:00
```

For more than one ID consider using the below one :

```
select id , max(timestamp_diff) as timestamp_diff
  from
  (
    with t(ID,DESCRIPTION,TIMESTAMP) as
    (
     select 1,'RECEIVER',to_timestamp('00:10:00','HH24:MI:SS') from dual union all
     select 1,'SENDER',to_timestamp('00:08:00','HH24:MI:SS') from dual union all
     select 1,'EXECUTOR',to_timestamp('00:05:00','HH24:MI:SS') from dual union all
     select 1,'SENDER',to_timestamp('00:03:00','HH24:MI:SS') from dual union all
     select 2,'SENDER',to_timestamp('00:06:00','HH24:MI:SS') from dual union all
     select 2,'SENDER',to_timestamp('00:02:00','HH24:MI:SS') from dual 
    )
     select t.id, 
            t.timestamp - lag(t.timestamp) over 
            (partition by t.id order by t.id,t.timestamp desc) as timestamp_diff,
            row_number() over (order by t.id,t.timestamp) as rn,
            t.description 
       from t   
      where t.description = 'SENDER'
  )  
  group by id, description;

 ID    TIMESTAMP_DIFF
 -- --------------------
 1  -000000000 00:05:00
 2  -000000000 00:04:00
```